# Changing drop down list data on-the-fly

Tags: jquery, html, drop-down-menu

I have a select box with a number of options. When a selection is made, I replace the displayed text using JQuery:

```
$("#dropdownlist").change(function () {
    var selected = $(this).find(":selected");
    selected.text('foo');
});
```

I'd then like to restore the original value when the select is dropped down. How can I do this?

I've tried using the 'click' event but this gets fired multiple times throughout the selection process, meaning that 'foo' always gets overwritten.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this drop down has an open event?

Comment: What is the purpose of doing this? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @gdoron As far as I'm aware, an open event isn't available.

Comment: @elclanrs My options display detailed information to help the user make their selection. In the interests of a clean UI, I don't wish to display this once the user has made their choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Approach 1:** Just noticed that the below solution in approach 2 is not working when changed the drop down value using keyboard and tabbed out.

So in this approach I used a text box over the drop down, so you don't need to worry about changing the drop down value. [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/skram/DQUM4/2/)

PS: I have used JQuery UI [Position API](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Position)

```
var $ddInput = $("#dropdownInput");

$ddInput.position({
  my: "left top",
  at: "left top",
  of: "#dropdownlist"
});

$("#dropdownlist").change(function (event) {
    $ddInput.val('foo');
});
```

**Approach 2:** We need an int flag as the change is calling the click again, see my code below. [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/skram/DQUM4/1/)

```
var optionChanged = 0;

$("#dropdownlist").change(function (event) {
    var selected = $(this).find(":selected");
    selected.attr('data-orig', selected.val());
    selected.text('foo');
    optionChanged = 1;       
});

$("#dropdownlist").click (function () {     

    if (optionChanged == 2) {
        var selected = $(this).find(":selected");
        var tmp = selected.attr('data-orig');
        selected.attr('data-orig', selected.val());
        selected.text(tmp);      
    }
    optionChanged = 2;       
});
```

Comment: Fantastic solutions - especially the first. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try a data property like:

```
selected.attr('data-oldtext', selected.text());
```

Before you change it.

The element must be "rendered" with the attribute empty or with the original text already.

```
<option data-oldtext="">xxx</option>
```

Comment: His problem is when to restore it, anyway, `.data('oldtext')` is better.

Comment: Using the "mouse" events to change and restore depending if it is over or going off the select element may work. Am I right?